# Python Pyqt4 showing only file name in dirlist with QlistWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qlistwidget, qicon

```
listWidget = QListWidget()
listWidget.setAcceptDrops(True)
listWidget.setDragEnabled(True)
path1 = "/home/hsa/Downloads/chap10/images/"
list_dir = set()
for image in sorted(os.listdir(path1)):
    item1 = os.path.join(path1,image)
    list_dir.add(item1)
    item = QListWidgetItem(item1)
    item.setIcon(QIcon(item1))
    listWidget.addItem(item)

iconListWidget = QListWidget()
iconListWidget.setAcceptDrops(True)
iconListWidget.setDragEnabled(True)
iconListWidget.setViewMode(QListWidget.IconMode)
```

With below code, I want to view only file name in dirlist using QListWidget.

How can I do that?

Comment: If you want that, why are you using `os.path.join`?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much ekhumoro for your answer.

I have arranged the code like below and solved.

```
item = QListWidgetItem(image)
item.setIcon(QIcon(item1))
listWidget.addItem(item)
```